# Django Template Language - URL Based On Template {{ value }}

Tags: django, url, django-templates

Let's say I have, in context, a JSON called "rows", and each row has 2 fields: a and b.
I wish to make b a url parameter and pass to a url call, like this:

```
{% for row in rows %}
<tr>
<td>{{ row.a }}</td>
<td><a href = "{% url 'some url' param={{ row.b }} %}">{{ row.b }}</a></td>
<tr>
```

The above code is invalid. How to do this?

Comment: `<a href = "{% url 'some url' param=row.b %}">{{ row.b }}</a>`

Answer (score 0):

With already having a pair of brackets outside, you don't need another pair of brackets inside. simply put:

```
<td><a href = "{% url 'some url' param = row.b %}">{{ row.b }}</a></td>
```